# C++, how to change variables of another class with a thread of another class

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have two classes A and B. What I want is class B to change a variable of class A using pthread.h:

```
class A
{
public:
    double v;
}
class B 
{
public:
    void commencingExecution(A& a);
    static void * setVHelper(void* context);
    void setV(A& a);
}



void B::commencingExecution(A& a);
{
    pthread_t set_v_thread;
    int iret = pthread_create(&set_v_thread, NULL, B::setVHelper, this);
}

void * B::setVHelper(void* context)
{
    while(1)
    {
        ((B *)context)->setV();
    }
}

void B::setV(A& a)
{
    a.v = 1;
}
```

The problem is that *static void* setVHelper(void* context)* can have only a single argument.... So how can I change a variable from another class?

Comment: If setVHelper can only have a single argument of type void*, can you just make a struct that consists of a pointer to class A and a pointer to class B and pass that as the parameter? `struct { A *a_ptr; B *b_ptr } param_struct;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct with being restricted to a single argument. The third argument that pthread_create takes is a `void* start_routine(void* argument)`. The way you get around this is packaging what you need for the child thread into a struct. In the provided example, between the class declaration of B and the function implementations, add something along the lines of

```
struct thread_arguments
{
    A* a_ptr;
}
```

Then before you call pthread_create, create a dynamically allocated struct and pass that as the fourth argumetn to pthread_create:

```
thread_arguments* args = new thread_arguments;
args.a_ptr = &a;
int iret = pthread_create(&set_v_thread, NULL, B::setVHelper, args);
```

Boom! You've snuck some extra info into the child thread. There's another change you'll have to make to your setVHelper function as well. Since it comes as a void pointer, you'll have to cast it to the struct type you just defined. So before the while loop you have:

```
thread_arguments* context = (thread_arguments*)context_ptr;
```

Now you will be able to access the struct you passed to the child thread via arrow notation.

```
while(1)
{
   setV(context_ptr->a_ptr);
}
```

Couple side notes, 1.) I recommended you package a pointer into the struct because it avoids unnecessary copying of objects. 2.) With your function defined as is your example would have failed anyways because an object of class A must be passed as an argument in `setV`. 3) Make sure you clean up the struct when you're done with it :)